# TSQL - comparing grouped values within a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, compare, sqlcompare

I need to compare grouped data to look for shifts in a calculated value.  The output of my current SQL looks something like this...

```
Grp_ID_1 / Metric / State / Value
A   Metric1 OH  50
B   Metric1 OH  65
A   Metric1 CA  20
B   Metric1 CA  35
```

In the example above, I need to calculate the difference between A-Metric1-OH value of 50 and B-metric1-OH value of 65.

Comment: lookup how to PIVOT

Comment: doing a little research, it appears that I have to define every column in pivot.  For this particular example, I would need to list all 50 states.  Other comparisons are even more complex.  This seems inefficient.  Need a way to simply state the subgroups (metric/state) and then compare across the two groupIDs.  Will always have 2 groups, base/test sort of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to calculate difference between rows.

```
SELECT LEAD(State, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Grp_ID_1 ) AS NextState ,
State - LEAD(State, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Grp_ID_1 ) AS StateDif
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT  grp_ID_1, metric, state, value,       
                (SELECT  MAX(value) 
                    FROM tablename   
                 ) - value AS Difference

        FROM tablename  group by state, grp_ID_1, metric, value  
        having state = 'OH'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may want to improve your answer by making it less tentative (don't use "try this") and adding a short explanation of the crucial part. For future readers it's not clear if a suggestion to try something was helpful or not.